# constexpr-ness of std::optional<T>::value_or

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17

As shown by [this page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/value_or), the rvalue ref-qualified version of `std::optional<T>::value_or` is not marked `constexpr`:

```
template< class U >
constexpr T value_or( U&& default_value ) const&;

template< class U >
T value_or( U&& default_value ) &&;
```

What's the reasoning behind this? Is it because the move of the value can modify the `optional` object?

But if we make the `&&` version also `constexpr`, isn't it good that we can now write:

```
constexpr int x = std::optional<int>(123).value_or(456);
```

Comment: cppreference typo. Fixed.

Comment: @T.C. That was *fast*.

Comment: It seems that the [Library Fundamentals TS](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2016/n4600.html#optional.object.observe.24) also needs to be fixed.

Comment: @T.C. Are you certain C++17 doesn't have that problem?

Comment: @Yakk It won't. https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/pull/839

Comment: No point keeping this open, so I've voted to close as a typo ... even though it was in the spec not the question :)